# stringr: regex to match and extract strings (including unique substrings) containing same substring

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

So I have a column in a dataframe that contains some names like this:

```
colnames <- c("YouAreHappy","YouAreHappy1", "YouAreHappy2", "NiceSmiles", "NiceSmiles1", "NiceSmiles2")
```

I am trying to use `stringr`'s `str_extract` function to extract only a specific part of the names, namely things like "Happy", "Happy1", "Happy2", "Smiles", "Smiles1", and "Smiles2".

I tried to use regex with `str_extract' as follows:

```
> str_extract(colnames, regex("Happy|Happy1|Happy2|Smiles|Smiles1|Smiles2"))
[1] "Happy"  "Happy"  "Happy"  "Smiles" "Smiles" "Smiles"
```

But I want extract:

```
[1] "Happy"  "Happy1"  "Happy2"  "Smiles" "Smiles1" "Smiles2"
```

I am obviously going about this wrong, but I do not know where and how. I get that the `|` implies `OR` but I don't know enough about regex to circumvent this hurdle. I am completely new to regular expressions and the like (just discovered [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/)), so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The longer patterns with common prefix must precede the shorter ones. Or, you could use `Happy\\d*|Smiles\\d*`, `str_extract(colnames, "Happy\\d*|Smiles\\d*")`

Comment: Or, `(Happy|Smiles)\\d*`

Comment: Is you goal only to check if certain substrings are present in your big strings array ?

Comment: @Yanis, the goal is to check and extract. I am eager to learn more about your idea, so would appreciate if you would expand.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you so much, both your solutions work perfectly. I assume `\\d*` is to account for the digits? What if I had a string like `"HappyFamily"`? I assumed `Happy\\w*` would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: It matches - https://ideone.com/EdSZ2N

Comment: I tried `str_extract(colnames, "Happy\\d*|Smiles\\d*|Happy\\w*")` which gave me `"Happy"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `Happy|Happy1|Happy2|Smiles|Smiles1|Smiles2` pattern, remember that the first alternative that matches "wins" and the ICU regex engine (used in *stringr*) does not consider the following alternatives. Note that several alternatives in your regex may match at the same location, and the shorter comes before longer ones. That is why the result is not as expected. See [*Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

It is true that TRE regex engine works differently. `regmatches(colnames, gregexpr("Happy|Happy1|Happy2|Smiles|Smiles1|Smiles2", colnames))` will get you the expected matches, because it is a text-directed regex engine and the longest matching alternative "wins". See [*Text-Directed Engine Returns the Longest Match*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

However, you may just use

```
"(Smiles|Happy)\\d*"
```

in both engines to get the same output. Make sure the alternatives do not match at the same location in the string, it is the best practice. `(Smiles|Happy)\d*` matches either `Smiles` or `Happy` and then 0 or more digits.